# An internal server error has occurred on Experience cloud site with embedded Google Map

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, experience-cloud, gack, google-map

On our **experience cloud site** there is an **embedded google map location** which throws this error everytime we open it. That map was already working earlier but now it started to produce this error in the past week.

> An internal server error has occurred
>
> An error has occurred while processing your request. The
> salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you
> believe you have additional information that may be of help in
> reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce
> Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any
> error id shown on this page as well as any other related information.
> We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using
> salesforce.com!
>
> Error ID: 1723691009-44060 (-1685232593)

I've already read through everything about gacks, and also opened a support ticket, so now I'am waiting for an answer and while waiting I opened this thread so I can help fellow developers who encounter a [gack](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack). If there is anything else I can do please let me know.

> Another way is to post your experience on Stack Exchange. You can post
> the gack ID and stack trace ID, along with information on how it was
> that you encountered our lovely message. We will be able to find it
> there when doing our investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently experiencing the same bug, I dont know when it started and I dont know how to fix it.

The only thing I know is that it works in the partial and dev orgs. Only in the production environment it has an error (At least on my side).

After searching the code, I found something interesting. When you use lightning-map it adds an iFrame to the site. Depending on whether you are in production or in a development org, the following url is used in the iFrame:

- Production: https://maps.a.forceusercontent.com:443/lightningmaps/mapsloader?version=244&resource=primitiveMap
- Partial or Dev: https://maps.b.forceusercontent.com:443/lightningmaps/mapsloader?version=246&resource=primitiveMap&region=US&language=en-US

Hint: In the documentation of the lightning-map you can see that the site "maps.a.forceusercontent.com" is mentioned. That means the URL belongs to salesforce, but i dont understand why the port number is used in the iFrame.
Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation

When you open the link from the production, you get the same error message.

If you decide to add the query parameters "&region=US&language=en-US" to the link, then it will work (https://maps.a.forceusercontent.com:443/lightningmaps/mapsloader?version=244&resource=primitiveMap&region=US&language=en-US).

Simply changing the .a. to .b. at the beginning will also make the map work (https://maps.b.forceusercontent.com:443/lightningmaps/mapsloader?version=244&resource=primitiveMap).

I do not know if this information is helpful, but I wanted to mention it.

Comment: The bug was fixed for me. There was no action on our part, Salesforce must have patched it in the background.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The issue was fixed for us too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you faced was a multi-customer issue. The GACK -1685232593 points to  `java.lang.NullPointerException` and the Salesforce Product team has filed a bug `#W-14417472` internally to fix the issue.

The bug fix was rolled out on Winter'23 Patch 13 release(246.13). You can monitor the release for your instance on https://status.salesforce.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The issue seems to be resolved!